# script to automatically combine data from different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I need a script to automatically combine text from several columns into one after the new Google Form is submitted.
I cannot use the simple formula e.g. =A1&B1&C1 and so forth for the rest of the rows because I'm using the Google Forms and when submitting a new answer to the sheet, it creates a complete new row with the answer and the formula is not working with it.
Can someone help me with writing the script??
I have searched everything and couldn't find similar question and answer to that.

Have you done your christmans good deed already? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So i just tested this out with a dummy form I made, and it works, since you only add the formula into one cell, it automatically expands as needed:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A:A>1,A:A&B:B&C:C,""))
```

Comment: With your formula, it combines data into one cell (as it seems to me) but I need to combine row by row from different columns. Any other thoughts? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by different columns? Do you mean that its not always A,b and c and you need the whole row? If so I, I have that formula too, as I tried a few variations on it when i tested

Comment: Have you actually tried the formula i added? that is exactly what it does... you dont need to extend it, the array formula portion, causes it to add the  formula by default for every new row, each row is only adding data for that particular row. I manually tested this out with a form and response sheet.

Comment: Yes I did but got an error:
Invalid content
Error
Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (224).

Comment: Look yourself - I entered the formula into D225:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zPnzTpfP6nChy98q6D7IBULScgm_QihHOrdpQPfgdM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, one sec im looking now, just have to restart my computer, its loading slowly - typically, you want to be adding this into an empty column, not 225 down, but im going to test somethign else, and let you know, since i can't edit on your sheet, ill get back to you in a sec

Comment: Actually, after entering your formula, the spreadsheet got slow, continously calculating formulas as you can see from the right upper corner of the window, there is the calculating bar. That's why I also believe a script would work better.

Comment: by the way, you should be able to edit my sheet.

Comment: Yeah, delete the formula first, its trying to calculate for the columns that are exisiting - just FYI, the reason I wrote it that way was because you specified that you were starting at the top of the sheet, next time it's just good to include that detail, that you trying to add it to a  column, halfway down - and when i tried to fix it, it said i didnt have permission

Comment: you have it under "protected ranges" so you need to remove the validation for me to remove/fix the formula

Comment: I had to delete this spreadsheet - it was not loading anymore the page even after I deleted your formula. Anyway, did you get the point what I'm trying here..?

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(if(A225:A>1,E225:E&F225:F,""))

Comment: here is an example form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14CvjAyc94-w8nF50LDgOG4Gmi6rTD8RxrgGp0TmINzY/viewform    and the example responses sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXGPkEk6mtzHdy8ynYXjUlfYvaQbygloEKKMh4ZTOoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I got it to work - thanks a lot! :)

Comment: no problem :) glad it worked! Can you please accept the answer when you get a chance? thanks!